# Lambda Expression for Unpivoting DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, linq, lambda, linq-to-dataset

I am reading data from an Excel sheet in the following format:

[image]

I need to store the data in the following way:

[image]

I am trying to do it with the help of Linq lambda expression but I think I'm not getting anywhere with this.

```
DataTable dataTable= ReadExcel();
var dt = dataTable.AsEnumerable();

var resultSet = dt.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Field<String>("Project_Code")))
                .GroupBy(x =>
                            new
                            {
                                Month = x.Field<String>("Month"),
                                ProjectCode = x.Field<String>("Project_Code"),
                                //change designation columns into row data and then group on it 
                                //Designation = 
                            }
                        );
                //.Select(p =>
                //            new
                //            {
                //                Month= p.d
                //            }
                //        );`
```

Comment: I would recommend using Power Query to unpivot your data - much easier!

Comment: Hi Charles. I was wondering if we could do it with the help of Lambda expressions. Power Query is something I would need to explore first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use ToDictionary with a pre-defined set of designation names:

```
private static readonly string[] designationNames = {"PA","A","SA","M","SM","CON"};
void Function()
{
    /* ... */
    var resultSet = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Field<String>("Project_Code")))
            .Select(x =>
                new
                {
                    Month = x.Field<String>("Month"),
                    ProjectCode = x.Field<String>("Project_Code"),
                    Designations = designationNames.ToDictionary(d => d, d => x.Field<int>(d))
                }
            );
}
```

This is the normalized version. If you want it flat instead, use:

```
private static readonly string[] designationNames = {"PA","A","SA","M","SM","CON"};

void Function()
{
    /* ... */
    var resultSet = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Field<String>("Project_Code")))
        .Select(x =>
            designationNames.Select(
                d =>
                    new
                    {
                        Month = x.Field<String>("Month"),
                        ProjectCode = x.Field<String>("Project_Code"),
                        Designation = d,
                        Count = x.Field<int>(d)
                    }
            )
        ).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
}
```

If the type is not always int then you might want to use `x.Field<String>(d)` instead and check for validity.

Comment: Worked like a charm! :)

Comment: I had to add AsEnumerable() on the data table, so `var resultSet = dt.AsEnumerable().Where ...` otherwise I was getting a "'Datatable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' ..." error.